# How to create a search bar like the one of interactive report for classic report

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

Here is my problem, how to create a search bar like this one :
[Search bar from Sample Database Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSKDk.png)
Only for a classic report, located in a modal page.

---

My current environnement is:

- Oracle EE - 12.1
- Apex      - 22.2.0
- ORDS      - 21.4

It is not possible for me to upgrade or downgrade these versions of software.

---

I cannot use an interactive report since the query is entered by a user which will be inserted in the report. IR do not support different column lenght at runtime.

I don't need to have all the functionnalities of the interactive report too, i only need those two :
[Sort column specifier - Interactive report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJAyO.png)
and
[Sort Action - Interactive report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAdUY.png)
with a search bar, and a reset button.
And it would be perfect if the look and feel stayed.

PS: These photos are from the Sample Databse Application in page 2 of Apex Template Applications.

---

So, here is what I have started :
[Search bar created manually (design)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MYvB.png)

My problem are the following:

- How to create a attribute `data-menu` like in the template application for the button which will contain the column names and the option case-sensitive ;
- How to then modify the placeholder field according to the values selected ;
- How to do a search through different columns with the field Search;
- How to create the sort option like shown in a previous picture

---

Any help will be appreciated, specially if you have exemples, thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Matthew, welcome to SO! Please read [ How do I ask a good question? ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A good question is concise, targets a single problem and some code (a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). All of this will make it easier for us to help you and will translate in you getting better ans faster answers.

Comment: Hi Axel, thank you for your comment. I understand there was too much details. I hope now it is more concise.

Comment: Why would you want to "make something similar to interactive report" if you could just create an interactive report ?

Comment: Because i need a report for different queries retuned by a PL/SQL function which, as i understand, interactive report do not support. Hence my need for classic report.

Comment: IR does support "Function body returning SQL Query" as source type. It didn't in older versions, but the functionality has been around for a couple of years already.

Comment: That is not the issue (sorry I did not explained well). The problem is that the Function body returns different number of column depending on a user input, so the IR doesn't accept the Function as valid. If you can point me to an exemple where a user enters a query and the IR just adapt, that would solve all problems. But from what I found, in my research, it doesn't work (yet?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people stuck on the same problems, I have some ways to start solving them. Although it isn't as pretty as I would expect it to be, it could allow you to start doing something functionnal without hard-coding your way into Apex.

So, in order:

- **How to create an attribute 'data-menu'**

For that, you can follow this link (https://doyensys.com/blogs/popup-menu-in-apex/) which will explain how to do a pop-up menu easily.
Only problem for this, is that in Apex, the Shared Components > List are static are (source values of the pop-up) meaning that, in my case, I cannot create the list of columns at run-time when getting them.

- **Modify a placeholder**

I though it was going to be much more complicated than what I found. For this, only create a 'Execute JS Code' in a Dynamic Action and modify the placeholder by changing the value with `$('#SEARCH_BAR').attr("placeholder", "The new placeholder")`. For my case, I first check the value and then modify it.
So like this:

```
if ($('#SEARCH_BAR').attr("placeholder") == "Search: All Texts Columns" && ...){
        $('#SEARCH_BAR').attr("placeholder", "The new placeholder")
}
```

(SEARCH_BAR being the static ID of the search bar of course).

- **How to do a search through different columns with the field Search**

Relatively simple. Since in the PL/SQL Function Body of my report returning the query, I am enabling/disabling the case sensitive option in function of an item value, the search bar is the same principle. I only need to create a where condition to check if the keyword like `%keword%` exists in one of the column (meaning creating a loop getting all the column name since it is dynamic), and only show those values.

- **How to create the sort option like shown in a previous picture**

This, I didn't find but I am not going to implement it. If someone ever find the solution, I am interested.

This may not be the most complete anwer but I hope that the next person having these issues will go quicker by stating from this.